# Добавление js элементов

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код в котором при нажатии на `input` добавляется `div` элемент.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi") ;
var length = 1 ;
function add_input() {
 var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
 new_input.name = "my_input" ;
 var div = document.createElement('div') ;
 div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>' ;
 div.appendChild(new_input) ;
 p.appendChild(div) ;
 length++ ;
} ;
```

```html
<select>
<option value="1" onclick="add_input();">1</option>
<option value="2" onclick="add_input();">2</option>
<option value="3" onclick="add_input();">3</option>
<option value="4" onclick="add_input();">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="add_input();" value="Добавить элемент">
<form>
<div id="inputi"><input name="my_input"></div>
</form>
```

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на `option` у нас создавался `div` c `input`, в котором будет занесен `value` `option`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="add_input_old()" value="Добавить элемент">
<form>
  <div id="inputi"><input name="my_input"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: заметил то что 2 раза 1 option не нажимается, нужно нажать другой option сначала.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, Так и должно быть, если нужно не так, не нужно использовать select